# I would like to calculate the number of days to the next meeting

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, vector

I would like to calculate the number of days to the next meeting given this as sample.

```
meetings=c("2023-06-21","2023-05-03","2023-03-22","2023-02-01","2022-12-07")
  

dates=c("2023-08-01","2023-04-01","2023-03-01","2023-02-01","2023-01-01")
```

and returning this

```
c(NA,32,21,0,31)
```

I have tried this but does not consider all meetings

```
as.Date(meetings)-as.Date(dates)
Time differences in days
[1] -41  32  21   0 -25
```

Comment: You can get all differences using  `outer(as.Date(meetings), as.Date(dates), "-")

Comment: This worked well and I had to find the lowest positive value for each "matrix column" to get the final answer.

Comment: You should post your solution as another answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First transform to date with `as.Date`. Sort the dates then use `sapply`, after defining next_meeting use `difftime`:

```
meetings <- as.Date(c("2023-06-21", "2023-05-03", "2023-03-22", "2023-02-01", "2022-12-07"))
dates <- as.Date(c("2023-08-01", "2023-04-01", "2023-03-01", "2023-02-01", "2023-01-01"))

meetings <- sort(meetings)

sapply(dates, function(date) {
  next_meeting <- meetings[which(meetings >= date)][1]
  if (is.na(next_meeting)) {
    return(NA)
  } else {
    return(as.integer(difftime(next_meeting, date, units = "days")))
  }
})
```

output:

```
[1] NA 32 21  0 31
```

Comment: That worked pretty well!

Answer (score 1):

This could also be done in dplyr 1.1.0+ using `join_by` & `closest`:

```
left_join(data.frame(dates = as.Date(dates)),
          data.frame(meetings = as.Date(meetings)),
          join_by(closest(dates <= meetings))) |>
  mutate(next_meeting = as.numeric(meetings - dates))



       dates   meetings next_meeting
1 2023-08-01       <NA>           NA
2 2023-04-01 2023-05-03           32
3 2023-03-01 2023-03-22           21
4 2023-02-01 2023-02-01            0
5 2023-01-01 2023-02-01           31
```

Comment: Many thanks! This worked really fine for a large amount of data.